# How do I substitute string and number values with a variable that says any string or any number?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# and need to rename a lot of files. They all follow the same naming convention. like AA-A0000-(1+)-A_words-sdsd_morewords. The only problem is the all follow this pattern but the A0000 and (1+) sections change file to file. How can I say if string follows that pattern than run my custom funciton on it?

How can I say if the file starts with two letters a hyphen the a letter followed by 4 numbers, another hyphen, a number, then another hyphen, then change the file name?

Comment: Wouldn't RegEx help?

Comment: Show us some related code, You can use string comparison using `YourFileName.StartsWith("AA-") && YourFileName.EndsWith("-A_words-sdsd_morewords")` or through a File filter like `AA-*-A_words-sdsd_morewords`. But it all depends on what have you tried so far.

Comment: As Crono said, RegEx is your answer.  That's exactly the kind of task it was designed for (pattern matching.)

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters have pointed out, Regular expressions are your answer. In .NET, this uses the Regex class. There are a number of tutorials for regular expressions that you can look at; the .NET version is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx.

Depending on how the different sections of the file name change in your example above, you can alter your regular expression to fit. So for instance,

```
Regex.Replace(fileName, @"[a-z ]+-A(\d{4}-\(\d+)", "BB-B$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Will match *AA-A0000-(1+)...*, *AA-A3456-(72+)...*, *C D-A3456-(72+)...*, etc, and replace the A's (and "C D") with B's. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFpUkW for an example of this in action.

Comment: How would I say if it matches [a-z] until it reaches a hyphen so it includes any number of letters and spaces

Comment: `[a-z ]+-` will match a-z and spaces followed by a hyphen (modified answer above)

Comment: thanks This is super helpful. Ive made some progress.

Comment: Don't forget to mark something as an answer if it answers the question you asked. That helps clear out questions from the "unanswered" category in StackOverflow and helps others who may stumble onto this question through google searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex.

If your filenames look, for example, like this:

```
aB-C0101-2-some text that contains-Numbers_01987etc.ext
```

then the pattern to match it would be:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]\d{4}-\d-[\s0-9a-zA-Z_-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3}
```

**Here are some additional resources:**

tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

to test a regex online (there are a lot more):

http://www.regexr.com/

http://www.regexplanet.com/

example use of `Regex.Replace()` method in C#:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace